# MS Access 2013 Run TIme [currentProject].[istrusted] Syntax

Tags: ms-access-2013

Hi I've an AutoExec macro in MS ACCESS 2007 works in MS ACCESS 2010 but not in 2013.  The macro calls [currentProject].[istrusted]=true .

What is the correct syntax for MS Access 2013 and how can I write a macro (or VBA module) that will detect the trusted status.

By the way I'm working with MS Access 2013 Run Time not the fully blown version of MS Access 2013.

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: Further to the above,  I have a VBA module that detects Application.Version. Is it possible to write  some VBA that will detect trusted status that caters for all versions of MS Access? That way I won't need to put this into a macro and keep adapting it to the inconsistencies in MS Access object models.

Comment: Think I've found my answer [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg435977%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this post while looking for an answer.  For several hours I banged around trying to get this to work in Access 2013 (Access 2007 worked).  In my scenario if content is enabled I want to load up the regular home form.  if content is not enabled I want to load up a form that just says to select to enable it.

The link from Tired_Eyes is great but it wouldn't work in my database.  I was getting prompts that Init() was unrecognized.  Using the same method in that link to open forms was also not effective.  What it was missing was the conditional.

What did work in Access 2013 was to create a macro - named autoexec.  In that macro select Action of "If" and in the box to the right of "If" put `[CurrentProject].[IsTrusted] = True`  Then in "Add New Action" dropdown select OpenForm and pick the form that should open if Content is enabled.  After that select "Add Else" and in the "Add New Action" dropdown select OpenForm and pick the form to display if content is not enabled.
[image: Sample Configuration]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add an If statement to your macro and insert the RunCode action into the If statement. I found it here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823046.aspx

Comment: Please post the solition here in case the link goes down for any reason.

Comment: this was the code in that link.

Sample code provided by: The  Microsoft Access 2010 Programmer’s Reference
  
`If [currentproject].[istrusted] Then
    RunCode
        Function Name =Init()

Else
    MessageBox
        Message The application is opened in disabled mode. Please enable the application for full functionality.
        Beep Yes
        Type None
        Title Disabled Mode Check

End If
`